# How to remove a innodb metadata lock with thread_id 0 in mariadb / mysql?

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.5

Today, suddenly our mysql database server got down. Few minutes after restarting the server went down again, and again. To see what is happening, we temporarily put our application in maintenance mode and found that the database didn't go down anymore. This helped me to find out what was happening;

Every `UPDATE` or `INSERT` on one specific table caused lots of `SELECT` queries (on that same table) to "Waiting for table metadata lock". As a result of that many open connections already appear within a few seconds and finally the server is crashing.
I couldn't understand why a simple `UPDATE app.notes SET user_id=5 WHERE note_id=1`  query took so long and even after 10 minutes waiting wasn't finished. The `SHOW PROCESSLIST` state on that query was still Executing.

Again, I restarted the server and after some research, I found that there is one metadata lock on that specific table

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT * FROM information_schema.METADATA_LOCK_INFO;
+-----------+------------+---------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+
| THREAD_ID | LOCK_MODE  | LOCK_DURATION | LOCK_TYPE           | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME |
+-----------+------------+---------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+
|         0 | MDL_SHARED | NULL          | Table metadata lock | app          | notes      |
+-----------+------------+---------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

But since that `THREAD_ID` is 0, I can't find anything how to delete the lock.

So where I am at the moment; the server is rebooted, MySQL is started, no query has been executed yet on that specific table and that one metalock on app.notes is still there.

All these have empty results:

Transaction section in `SHOW ENGINE innodb STATUS;`

`SELECT * FROM INNODB_LOCK_WAITS;`

`SELECT * FROM INNODB_LOCKS;`

`SELECT * FROM INNODB_TRX;`

`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`

I've already tried to `DROP TABLE` but that also results in "Waiting for table metadata lock".

What can I do or try to make the lock go away??

Comment: What is the result of `SELECT @@autocommit;`? If it's `0`, then there's an open transaction somewhere. If you are not using explicit commits, be sure this is set to `1`.

Comment: The result of ```SELECT @@autocommit;``` is ```1```

Comment: Does `app.notes` have its primary key as `note_id`? A 10 minute query suggest it isn't and that changing this will increase its speed. As you noted the `MDL_LOCK_MODE` is `MDL_SHARED`.  The `MDL` is there to prevent `DROP` and `ALTER TABLE` while queries are running. `Thread 0` is your current query. Include your mariadb logs, I think you are on the wrong track with the metadata lock hunt, these effects don't cause a server to go down.

Comment: Yes ```note_id``` is the primary key of the table. It's a 24MB table with ~31.000 rows. It's a heavily used table in the application. But let me mention again that specific ```MDL_SHARED``` lock is already there when I fully rebooted the machine and 0 queries have been executed since.

Comment: `Thread 0` based on your answer was probably the undo/redo logs being applied and holding the lock. These where taking so long because your innodb buffer pool size and/or innodb log file size are far too small. This would also explain why basic `UPDATE` stalls so long. Fix these and you might be saved from very many questionable scenarios. The cause of your crash is still not obvious. Include the logs.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching and trying, I found that the solution was to put innodb in recovery mode with `innodb_force_recovery = 3`. Now the lock was gone immediately. I dropped the table, then recovery mode back off `innodb_force_recovery = 0` and recreated the table from a backup.